# Rendering and saving report file to .pdf

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I made app to create reports and save it as .pdf At mine computer after creating report i use this code to save it as .pdf

```
   Try

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("C:\" & Form1.TextBox2.Text & "_Report.pdf", ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("pdf"), False)

        MessageBox.Show("Exported to .pdf file on at location C:\", "Note ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

But when i send the application to someone else it won't create this the .pdf on other computer. What is required to be installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern windows computers normal users don't have the permission to access the "C:\" directory directly. When trying to access it with your code, you get a exception, which is in your example code silently ignored.

A better way is to store the file in the users personal folder. You can use the GetFolderPath method to get it:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

Comment: So if i use it like this "   `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & Form1.TextBox2.Text & "_Report.pdf", ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("pdf"), False)`
" i got the output DocumentsName_Report.pdf   How to avoid this prefix Documents

Comment: You need a slash '\' after GetFolderPath: `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\" & Form1.TextBox2.Text & "_Report.pdf", ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("pdf"), False)`